# How to open a list of urls on new tabs in Selenium + Python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Code snippet:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
urls =['fb.com','instgram.com' , 'youtube.com']
for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
driver.close()
```

The problem is that it opens the new link on top of the previous one. I want each site to open on a new tab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the first URL then for the rest, use `target: _blank` to open each URL in a new tab:

```
driver.get(urls[0])
for url in urls[1:]:
    driver.execute_script('window.open("{}", "_blank");'.format(url))
```

And voila, you should have three tabs with three different URLs.

Note about your URLs: These are invalid. Make sure they each have `http` or `https` in front of them. And you've accidentally wrote *instgram* instead of *instagram*. :P

Comment: Is there any advantage in terms of memory while using this?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, although I'm not so familiar with the memory aspects